# Installing unsigned x64 driver to work with libusbdotnet

Tags: libusb

I am currently in a Windows 7 dev. environment working to get a device to initialize with [libusbdotnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libusbdotnet/).

The device (a USB mass storage device) connects and runs using the default USB-MASS Storage driver for Windows. I want to replace this driver with the one created by the .INF Wizard in libusbdotnet.

The operating system is a 64-bit, and by default the INF Wizard produces this driver, but I am unable to selected it because it is "unsigned" I believed, when I go to "Pick from a list of drivers" and point to the directory where the newly created device drivers are.

I have enabled "TEST MODE" using DESO but I'm still unable to select this file.

Anyone familiar with libusbdotnet, or directing devices to work with a specific driver that is unsigned in Window (do I need the .inf file? or the .sys???) do you have any advice about where I'm going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm starting to believe the problem lies in the fact that my device is a USB to ATA/ATAPI bridge, and that once it has been connected there isn't really any information about the device, but instead the device is added to ATA/ATAPI devices and uninitialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

64-bit windows doesn't like unsigned drivers.  You need to get a Software Publishing Certificate from MS (costs a few hundred $$$).  Then you need to use inf2cat to make a security catalog out of your inf and sys files, then you sign them with signtool and your SPC.  Then they will install on 64-bit Windows.

You can create your own self-signed certificate, without paying MS.  However, the self-signed certs only work on your machine, and only work in Test Mode.